# Styled Components and Material Ui

Tags: material-ui, styled-components

Can I use Styled Components and Material Ui at the same time for the same react app that I'm building for the front end? will there be any problems that I will face during the development phase?

Comment: Which version of Mui are you using?

Comment: Yes you can. About the problems, it is hard to tell, because, of course, there always is a possibility of problem during development. But I'm using both with a lot of project, and I know this is possible. Previously I used StyleComponents, but now I'm using Emotion's StyleComponents. If you encounter an issue and couldn't find the answer let as know.